# Where is AWS Glue Data Catalog stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm studying Glue Data Catalog and I'm a bit confused. I know that Glue Data Catalog doesn't store the data itself but just the metadata for the databases and tables, but still, where is the location in which they are stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on publicly available information, Glue Catalog is a [drop in replacement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html) to Hive Metatore. It is highly likely that the architecture is very similar to Hive Metastore. At a high level, the Hive metastore consists of a Java server and a MySQL database. The [admin manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+Administration#AdminManualMetastoreAdministration-RemoteMetastoreDatabase) provides more details.

So the metadata must be stored in a MySQL database managed internally by AWS. This is speculation as there is no concrete information available publicly.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the closest one can get to the answer given that there is no public info on this.

Comment: I am interested in the same question. Did you find out more? 

I am curious, is the metadata of the glue data catalog stored in S3? If yes, where can we find it? Can we store metadata for different databases in different locations?

Comment: Also begs the question about how to backup and restore the Glue Catalog...